# Error parsing json retrofit android array

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit

I have this json.

```
{ 
"people":
 [
  { "id":0, "person":true },
  { "id":1, "person":true }
 ] 
}
```

Model

```
class Person(var id: Int, var person: Boolean)
```

My endpoint request

```
@GET("/posts")
    fun getPeople(): Call<List<Person>>
```

And after request I have failure response and message

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you need to create a wrapper around the list itself that contains the `people` property.

So you should have something like

```kotlin
data class PeopleList(
  var people: List<Person>
)
```

which should then be used in your service definition like

```kotlin
@GET("/posts")
fun getPeople(): Call<PeopleList>
```

The reason for this is that retrofit is expects a JSON list `[...]`, but the data being sent is a JSON object `{...}` that **contains** a list. So you need to tell retrofit how to get to the list.

Comment: I have done wrapper for the list , but I have the same error

Comment: And I have response status 200, I have just problem with parsing